# C Shared memory existing flag?

Tags: c, memory-management, shared-memory, sysv

I have seen that question on SO already but it wasn't clear to me the following case:

A shm has been created. So if I call in my case:

```
int shmid = shmget(key, sizeof(struct messageQueue), IPC_CREAT | S_IRWXU | IPC_EXCL);
```

shmid turns -1 if the shm already exists. But can i somewhere get it's ID? Or do I need to call shmget(...) without EXCL flag again in order to get the ID?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you have to call it again. This sounds like an XY problem, what is the overall goal?

Comment: When it returns error with EXCL and CREAT, just call it again without EXCL and CREAT to get an id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, `IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL` is used if you want to create and **initialize** a new memory block. E.g.:

```c
int shmid = shmget(key, sizeof(struct messageQueue), IPC_CREAT | S_IRWXU | IPC_EXCL);
if( shmid != -1 )
{
    /* initialization code */
}
/* if it already exists, open it: */
if( shmid == -1 && errno == EEXIST ) 
    shmid = shmget(key, sizeof(struct messageQueue), S_IRWXU );

if( shmid == -1 ) {
    perror("shmget");
}
```

If you don't need to initialize it, you can skip the `IPC_EXCL`:

```c
int shmid = shmget(key, sizeof(struct messageQueue), IPC_CREAT | S_IRWXU );
```

and if you don't need to create it, you can skip the `IPC_CREAT`:

```c
int shmid = shmget(key, sizeof(struct messageQueue), S_IRWXU );
```